# Unknown column 'activated' in 'field list', NOT

Tags: java, sql, jpa, orm, spring-data

I trying to do a simple insert in the database by using but getting the exception

> Unknown column 'activated' in 'field list'

```
 @NotNull
@Column(name = "activated")
private Boolean active;
```

the name on ORM is the same, the alter table as used like:

```
ALTER TABLE user
ADD activated BOOL
DEFAULT false;
```

curious is that when i try to save a FALSE value it goes ok!, but when the value is TRUE 
this error occurs, same with the opposite way, if a set the default value as true dont save false values.

i really want to know whats going on about it!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stacktrace, the code that produces the error as well as some more information.

Comment: The stack trace would be helpful.  Also, if this is a SQLException can you turn on logging of sql being executed and capture the sql being executed when the problem occurs?